# Unknown javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have the function

```
function bind(method, context) { 
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2); 
   return function() { 
       var a = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)); 
       return method.apply(context, a); 
    }
}
```

The question was: how this function working and for what it can be used.

I understand that function bind (and return function too) convert array-like arguments into a real array. Method and context is not converted into array (because of 2 index). I can pass extra args in bind function and args into returned function and call method with context as 'this'.

My question is - how it can be used, in what cases. Is method and context  - function or objects, or function and object?

Comment: It does the same that [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) does

Answer (score 1):

This function is usual to produce an event handler function.

When you subscribe to your function to an event, for example, and the function is called the `this` depends on which call your handler.

If you pass a method of your object instead a function, you want to access your object by `this`.

The function first 2 arguments are the method (the function you want to bind), the context (the object you want to access on `this`), and you could add some other fixed arguments, that will be pass to your handler function each time is called.

Then the function return a new function, that you use to subscribe the event listener you need, and this function get all the argument passed by this event and add to the arguments array.

And finally do the magic with `apply` that allow you to call a function changing the context and passing an arbitrary array as the arguments of the function.

You could use this kind of function not only in event subscribtion, but even in call like array `forEach`, `map` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, zerkms  and Mario! Both answers are very usefull for me. I understand how it works and for what it can be used. Thank you very much for this explanation!